# selenium2 chrome webdriver - workaround for a blocking confirm?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Sorry my question could not be more succinct.

I'm using Selenium 2.14.0.

I have two pages, test.html and test2.html.  I load test.html with the chrome webdriver, and click a link that takes me to test2.html.

test2.html contains a confirm in the body, which I think is preventing the page from loading, which is blocking my test script.  Below are the html pages and my test script.

Is there anyway to have selenium2 close the confirm dialog?  It looks like there is a way to do it with selenium-rc (choose_ok_on_next_confirmation), but that functionality is not available in webdriver (AFAICT).

When I run my test script, I don't get the 'blocking' output until I close the confirm.  Funny thing is, if I load test2.html directly from my test script, instead of clicking a link, it doesn't seem to block.

Test.html

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="link" href="test2.html">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Test2.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a id="link" href="test2.html">Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Python selenium test script

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
wd.get('file:///C:/cygwin/tmp/postest/test.html')
elem = wd.find_element_by_id('link')
elem.click()
print 'Blocking!'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

?

Comment: Well, it blocks after clicking the link, so that code would never be executed.  Thanks, though.